# Getting multiple buttons from same class name (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping fb for learning.

I am writing the following lines but it is unable to find the button on the page. (i don't want to use href because the href would be different for different fb posts)

```
likeButton = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "_2e4w nowrap")))
likeButton[0].click #this code is never reached
```

and I have tried this as well

```
likeButton = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._2e4w.nowrap")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're scrapping HTML, so please tell me if this is not true.

Class names in HTML are not unique to things. Multiple objects in HTML may have the same class name, but generally multiple things will not have the same `id`. `id`'s are generally unique.

```
<thing id="some_id"></thing>
```

instead of

```
<thing class="some_class"></thing>
```

I would use classes to narrow down a search and then select with `id`s.

Also if there are css selectors that select classes, they look something like this:

```
.some_class {
    //some css
    color: example_color;
}
```

If they are based on `id`'s they look something like this

```
#some_id {
    //some css
    color: example_color;
}
```

EDIT:

I'm also guessting it's looking for a single class name. I would also try something like:

```
likeButton = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "_2e4w")))
```

If you want `nowrap` as well, there's probably a way to select multiple class names. I wouldn't expect `_2e4w.nowrap` to work.

Comment: yes this is a HTML file.
and the problem is that it is unable to detect the button through "class name"

Comment: what happens if you `pprint(likeButton)`. Is the object `None`?

Comment: it never reaches that part. because code is waiting for the like button to be displayed.

Comment: what happens when you just look for `_2e4w`?

Comment: it works. but it is only getting first button. (not returning a list of buttons)

Answer (score 0):

String input should be "_2e4w" not "_2e4w nowrap" these are two separate classes

To get a list of buttons "presence of all elements located" needs to be used

```
likeButton = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "_2e4w")))
```